# Laravel doesn't show image but url is correct

Tags: php, image, laravel

I want to get an image that is stored like this: public/pics/products.
Code:

```
<img src="{{ $shopGSM->productshot->first()->image }}" id="webshoppic">
```

The result:

```
<img src="pics/products/d132da08c7c01659edad47142261301b.jpg" id="webshoppic">
```

But no picture :(, what do i do wrong?

Comment: try to upload image in assets folder and use this <img src="/assets/

Comment: in this folder /public/assets/images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't include the site url in src attribute. use following code

`src="{{ URL::asset($shopGSM->productshot->first()->image)}}"`

This will return something like as follow

`src="http://www.domainName.com/pics/products/d132da08c7c01659edad47142261301b.jpg"`

Hope this will work for you

Comment: Cool... Keep developing @Wesley